# Scipy - Skimage - slic is not working with grayscale images

Tags: scipy

I want to segment my grayscale image as following:

```
img = io.imread(curr_img_path)
gray = color.rgb2gray(img)
assignment1 = slic(image=gray, n_segments=500, sigma=2, max_iter=100)
```

I am looking at the segmented image using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0, 0].imshow(mark_boundaries(gray, assignment1))
plt.show()
```

My problem: This shows me a normal grid. Like a chessboard. I do not understand why, and the docs say its possible using grayscale images. Any help? Btw: My image is of shape (352,1216), dtype= float64. There is no error message or something else. Would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

While the compactness parameter can be left to the default value for image in lab-space, the default parameter is to high for RGB/Grayscale images.